# Trying to use asp.net async page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have an ASP.NET (webforms) page that needs to call a stored procedure which may take up to a minute to return.  I realise that this is not ideal but the the database side of this project is out of my hands and hence I must live with this problem.

Basically I am looking for some method which will allow the page to render without the stored procedure hanging the page - with the results from the database call being displayed when available.

So, I am looking at an async page.  I have added "ASYNC=TRUE" to the top of the page and so far, I have the following:

```
private async void GetCampaignCounts(int CampaignID)
{
    Task t = new Task
    (
        () =>
        {

            CampaignService cs = new CampaignService();
            FilterSet.TargetCounts f = cs.GetCampaignDetails(CampaignID); //LONG RUNNING DB CALL

            if (f.Total > 0)
            {
                panelStatsLeft.Visible = true;

        //DO STUFF IN HERE
            }
            else
                panelStatsLeft.Visible = false;
        }
    );

    t.Start();
    await t;


}
```

However, this still hangs the page whilst the database query is running!

Am I doing something totally wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous requests in web applications are not intended to not hang the page. The request will still take the same time as the synchronous version. The benefits are in scalability (i.e. if your page could handle 100 simultaneous users before it would be able to handle 1000 if it is async on the same hardware assuming that the bottleneck was the request pipeline and not the database).

If you want to make the page load and update itself when the operation completes I am afraid you will need significantly more complex architecture. Your best bet is load the page and do an ajax request that runs the query and update the page when the request returns. It is a best practice to use async/await for this ajax request (again for scalability).

Answer (score 0):

Personally i wouldn't bother tying the two together. A better operation is to offload the query elsewhere and return later to get the results.

So use a signalling framework such as signalr.  Submit your report parameters,  pass them to msmq where they can be handled on a different server or use a one way wcf request.  When the request is received optionally store the result in the database and use signalling to notify client (either passing them the actual result or telling them the url where they can download the report from (pick it up from the database in that other url)). Async that into the users current browser page which presumably has a spinner saying "hey we are generating your report".

Consider signalling too.

Answer (score 0):

As I describe in my MSDN article on the topic, [`async` on ASP.NET is not a silver bullet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx):

> When some developers learn about async and await, they believe it’s a way for the server code to “yield” to the client (for example, the browser). However, async and await on ASP.NET only “yield” to the ASP.NET runtime; the HTTP protocol remains unchanged, and you still have only one response per request. If you needed SignalR or AJAX or UpdatePanel before async/await, you’ll still need SignalR or AJAX or UpdatePanel after async/await.

This makes sense if you think about the HTTP protocol: there can be only one response for each request, and `async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol (more detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html)). So, if you return a response to the client (allowing it to render the page), then that request is done. You can't send a followup response later to change the page you already sent.

The proper solution is fairly complex, because ASP.NET wasn't designed to track "background" operations without a request. ASP.NET will recycle your application periodically, and if there are no active requests, it assumes that it's a good time to do so. So, "background" operations are in danger of being terminated without notice.

For this reason, the best solution is to have an independent worker process that actually executes the background operation using a basic distributed architecture (requests are placed into a reliable queue by the ASP.NET handler; requests will re-enter the queue automatically if the worker process fails). This also means your requests should be idempotent.

If you don't want this level of complexity, you can trade-off reliability for complexity. An intermediate step is [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/), which requires a database backend at least (which it uses for reliability instead of a queue). If you want the least reliability (and least complexity), you can just use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` or my [ASP.NET Background Tasks library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks). I have a longer overview of these options [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).